# return all urls which contain string in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is super easy, but I want to run a jquery/javascript script to return an array of all URLs on a page v which contains the '601' within it.

Comment: Give us an example, what classifies as a *"URL on a page"* in the document?

Comment: sorry by URL I mean a href link.
e.g.
    <a class="link" href="https://www.xxxx.com/6012342342/example" </a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the selector `a[href*='601']` to get each element which `href` contains the text `"601"`. For putting them in array you can use `.each()` and then `push()` the `href` attributes:

```js
var arr = [];
$("a[href*='601']").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).attr('href'));
})
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="xxxx.com/6012342342/example"></a> 
<a class="link" href="xxxx.com/2342342/example"></a>
<a class="link" href="xxxx.com/2342342/example601"></a>
<a class="link" href="xxxx.com/6012342342/601example"></a>
<a class="link" href="xxxx.com/foo/example"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = $("[href*=601]").map(function(){return $(this).attr('href')})
```

Comment: Hi Md Adil,
That only returns the first href containing 601 but there is alot on the page and i need an array of them.

Comment: Sorry, I was hurry, check out this update again.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter your array with all urls. And [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to determine if the URL contains `"601"`.

```
var urls = ['example.com','example.com/601'];

var filtered = urls.filter(function(url){
    return url.includes("601");
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/xepemuhuna/edit?js,console)

Edit:

Sorry I didn't see you also want do get all link elements first.

```
var urls = [];
$("a").each(function() { 
    urls.push(this.href)
})
```

Then you could use my first method or directly use.

```
var filtered = [];
$("a").each(function() { 
    var url = this.href
    if (url.includes("601")) {
        filtered.push(url)
    }
})
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/qufoconise/edit?js,console)